# Is there a way to set a number of ports from generic in VHDL?

Tags: generics, port, vhdl, multiplexing

I'm facing a "problem", in the sense that I'm building a VHDL module that should give the possibility to take at out a port from N at input, so a MUX, but my concern is about the input ports, as they come from other modules instanciated in the design, and they could be from 1 up to N (I can have the generic N).
My question is: is there a way to implement N input ports of my mux, if N is a generic? I wouldn't want to have too many of them and go for the worst case of the maximum allowed N and instanciate them one by one.
I had already thought about using only one input port of width **N*datawidth** and then multiplexing by selecting the correct range of that larger port, but my tutors didn't like the solution, because from block design (the module is part of an IP Core) it would be messy to connect the ports from the other modules to my mux correctly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: An array of the element type would work great.   Note if the element type is an array, then you create an array of an array.    Then the Mux is simple - just index the array.

Comment: The input element type is actually composed by 6 ports, 2 of data and 4 flags, so are you suggesting to use a custom type that defines the input element and then use an array of it?

Comment: Show the design and implementation with all of the ugly ports and then we can help you fix it.

Comment: In the end i spoke with my tutors, I'm going for the manual writing of all the input ports and then I will istanciate another module managing the separation and  and multiplexing internally, thanks anyway